# Calling method from unit test fails with "does not contain a definition" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have some troubles in my code... can u help me, please?

I have trying make a test unit on Visual Studio, here's the code:

```
public partial class frmCalculator : Form
{
    string operand1 = string.Empty;
    string operand2 = string.Empty;
    string result;
    char operation;

    public frmCalculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmCalculator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnOne.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btnTwo.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btnThree.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btnFour.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btnFive.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btnSix.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btnSeven.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btnEight.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btnNine.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btnZero.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        btnDot.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;

            switch (btn.Name)
            {
                case "btnOne":
                    txtInput.Text += "1";
                    break;
                case "btnTwo":
                    txtInput.Text += "2";
                    break;
                case "btnThree":
                    txtInput.Text += "3";
                    break;
                case "btnFour":
                    txtInput.Text += "4";
                    break;
                case "btnFive":
                    txtInput.Text += "5";
                    break;
                case "btnSix":
                    txtInput.Text += "6";
                    break;
                case "btnSeven":
                    txtInput.Text += "7";
                    break;
                case "btnEight":
                    txtInput.Text += "8";
                    break;
                case "btnNine":
                    txtInput.Text += "9";
                    break;
                case "btnZero":
                    txtInput.Text += "0";
                    break;
                case "btnDot":
                    if(!txtInput.Text.Contains("."))
                        txtInput.Text += ".";
                    break;

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry for the inconvenience, Unexpected error occured. Details: " +
                ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void txtInput_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyChar)
        {
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
            case '0':
            //case '+':
            //case '-':
            //case '*':
            //case '/':
            //case '.':
                break;
            default:
                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Only numbers, +, -, ., *, / are allowed");
                break;
        }           
    }

    private void txtInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = txtInput.Text;
        operation = '+';
        txtInput.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void btnMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = txtInput.Text;
        operation = '-';
        txtInput.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void btnMulitply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = txtInput.Text;
        operation = '*';
        txtInput.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = txtInput.Text;
        operation = '/';
        txtInput.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    private void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        operand2 = txtInput.Text;

        double opr1, opr2;
        double.TryParse(operand1, out opr1);
        double.TryParse(operand2, out opr2);

        switch (operation)
        {
            case '+':
                result = (opr1 + opr2).ToString();
                break;

            case '-':
                result = (opr1 - opr2).ToString();
                break;

            case '*':
                result = (opr1 * opr2).ToString();
                break;

            case '/':
                if (opr2 != 0)
                {
                    result = (opr1 / opr2).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Can't divide by zero");
                }
                break;
        }

        txtInput.Text = result.ToString();
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtInput.Text = string.Empty;
        operand1 = string.Empty;
        operand2 = string.Empty;
    }

    private void btnSqrRoot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double opr1;
        if (double.TryParse(txtInput.Text, out opr1))
        {
            txtInput.Text = (Math.Sqrt(opr1)).ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnByTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double opr1;
        if (double.TryParse(txtInput.Text, out opr1))
        {
            txtInput.Text = (opr1 / 2).ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnByFour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double opr1;
        if (double.TryParse(txtInput.Text, out opr1))
        {
            txtInput.Text = (opr1 / 4).ToString();
        }
    }




}
```

and my Class Test:

```
[TestClass()]
public class frmCalculatorTests
{
    [TestMethod()]

    public void valor_limite_maximo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var calculadora = new frmCalculator();
        var retorno = calculadora.btnEqual_Click(123456789, 123456789);

        Assert.AreEqual(246913578, retorno);
    }
}
```

The message that the program show is:

> Error  1   'SimpleCalculator.frmCalculator' does not contain a definition for 'btnEqual_Click' and no extension method 'btnEqual_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'SimpleCalculator.frmCalculator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\milene\Desktop\nova calc-talvez certa\Simple Calculator\SimpleCalculatorTests\frmCalculatorTests.cs    21  39  SimpleCalculatorTests

How i can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
calculadora.btnEqual.PerformClick()
before that you have to initialize textes (the couple (123456789, 123456789) are not valid parameters).

**Edited**
You have to separate UI part from business logic.
For example:
Class CBusinessLogic
    void OnBtnClick(String name)
    {
         switch (name)
         {
             case "btnOne": view.AddInput("1")
             etc
         }
    }

'view' is a member of CBusinessLogic and is your object 'calculadora'. After creating the form, you create the CBusinessLogic class passing (in constructor for example) the object 'calculadora'. The form must also have a reference to the CBusinessLogic created.

The form must be changed to call the CBusinessLogic object:

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    businessLogic.OnBtnClick(btn.Name);
}

String GetInput()
{
    return txtInput;
}

void AddInput(String digit)
{
     txtInput.Text += digit;
}
```

This is the application of the design pattern MVC.
With it you can test your application calling methods such as
    String before=calculadora.GetInput();
    businessLogic.OnBtnClick("1");
and you can verify if input has changed
    String after=calculadora.GetInput();
    Assert.AreEqual(before+"1",after);

The parameters you use are wrong because btnEqual_Click expects an object "sender" (maybe the form or some other object who calls the method...sure not an integer) and arguments for the click (EventArgs), againt isnot an integer.
I think you want to simulate the result of "add operation". You have to use OnBtnClick("1") then OnBtnClick("2") ... OnBtnClick("9") for the first number. Then OnBtnPlusClick(). Then OnBtnClick("1")... etc for the second number, then OnBtnEqual(). 
At this point you can check if the result is what you expect.

Comment: You're right, btnEqual is private. :/
To do this kind of tests I use a mock view and move all the logic of the application inside a controller (MVP pattern). This way you overcome all theese private members/methods and the app becomes testable more easyly.

Comment: i dont got it your point....why the couple are not valid parameters? and how i can use the calculadora.btnEqual.PerformClick() before? creating another method? or instantiating?

Comment: so, my problem dont have solution? :/

Answer (score 1):

Those methods are marked as `private` so are not accessible outside of the scope of the form.